# Regress out covariates in a different order

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, multicollinearity

I got a list of covariates in the multiple linear regression

Y = X + cov1 + cov2 + ... + cov10

One of the covariates (e.g. cov1) is highly correlated with Y (Pearson's correlation = ~0.6).

I was wondering whether it will make a difference if I regress out the covariates in a different order:

Strategy #1: regress out all ten covariates at the same time,

```
> resid(lm(Y~cov1+cov2+..+cov10))
```

Strategy #2: regress out the cov1 first, then use the residuals to further regress out the remaining 9 covariates

```
> resid(lm(resid(lm(Y~cov1))~cov2+cov3+..+cov10))
```

Are these two strategies equivalent? Is the second strategy legitimate to use?

My understanding is that if we want to get an equivalent estimate from strategy #1 by two steps, we need to also regress out the cov1 from the other covariates, which is

> resid(lm(resid(lm(Y~cov1))~ cov2|cov1 + cov3|cov1 +..+ cov10|cov1))

Any comments are welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to read up on the Frisch Waugh Lovell theorem for results in this direction.

Comment: So indeed, for the 2nd strategy to be equivalent, you also need the residuals of the regression of the other covariates on cov1. What is $X$ in your first equation?

Comment: Hi Christoph, thanks for your comment. The FWL theorem resolved my confusion. The X in the first equation is a categorical variable coded as 0,1,2. I want to estimate the beta effect of X on Y. However, the cov1 is highly correlated with Y so I am worried about the collinearity bias, thus would like to use a proper regressing-out strategy.

Comment: Good! Notice, though, that since the two strategies are (indeed, numerically) equivalent, neither will be better/worse when regressor correlation is an issue. Also note that correlation of regressors induces no bias, but rather, possibly, imprecisely estimated coefficients.

Comment: Since the result of completing this process in *any* order is the usual multiple regression solution, the answer is evident.